# How does the input and output of a number sort an array in C?

Tags: c, sorting

How does the following code print a sorted array?  I cannot understand the logic behind this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[1000000];

int main(void) {
    int t, i = 0, temp;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        a[temp]++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++) {
        while (a[i] != 0) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
            a[i]--;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you debug your code and inspect the values you can see how it works. This is possible without the 1000000 iterations.

Comment: [It works like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

Comment: Don't enter a number outside the range 0..999,999 — life will be miserable, and those numbers will not be displayed.  The input code should check the value in `temp` before using it in `a[temp]++;`.  And the printing code access `a[1000000]` which is not part of the array; happiness is not likely to ensue (though there's also a decent chance the code won't crash — but the behaviour is undefined because of the out-of-bounds array access).

Comment: Think what happens if you say you'll enter 3 values, and you then enter the numbers 1, 2, 2.  What happens during the input loop?  What happens during the output loops?  What is `a` initialized to, given that it's a file scope (global) variable.

Comment: Thank you so much WhozCraig for your comment. I'll understand this and hopefully then i could understand and reply to other comments.

Comment: Jeroen Heier Thanks for your advice.I will consider this before posting a question further

Comment: Jonathan Leffler, This was a question for a competetive program.Thankfully the constraint allows me to declare a[1000000]. Input of all the elements as 0 can be done by initialisation..Thanks for your kind help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps are simple:

- The array `a` is used to count the number of occurrences of each number entered.
- The second loop iterates over this array, printing the numbers for which the count is non zero the corresponding number of times.

This very simple sort method is called counting sort.

Note that the program has shortcomings and potential bugs:

- the return values of `scanf()` are not tested, causing potential undefined behavior if the input fails conversion to integer.
- the numbers must be in the range `0` to `999999` inclusive. A number outside this range will cause undefined behavior.
- the final loop iterates up to `1000000` inclusively, accessing the array beyond the last element, causing undefined behavior.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[1000000];

int main(void) {
    int t, i, temp;
    if (scanf("%d", &t) != 1)
        return 1;
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &temp) != 1)
            return 1;
        if (temp < 0 || temp >= 1000000) {
            fprintf(stderr, "number is out of range: %d\n", temp);
            continue;
        }
        a[temp]++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        while (a[i] != 0) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
            a[i]--;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it up in smaller parts:

```
scanf("%d", &t);
```

This is simple: it asks the user an integer, and stores it in `t`. This variable represents how many integers we want to sort.

```
for(i = 0; i < t ; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &temp);
    a[temp]++;
}
```

This piece of code asks the user to input `t` integers. In each iteration, the value at position `temp` of the array `a` gets increased.

What does it mean? Think of the array `a` as an array of counters where each counter is initially set to 0. When the user enters a new integer `n`, the counter for `n` (i.e. `a[n]`) gets increased.

At the end of the loop, the `j`-th element of the array `a` stores the number of occurrences of the number `j`.

Suppose you have the following numbers to sort:
`4 1 8 7 6 7`

Before the first iteration: `a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]`

1. `a[4]++ => a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]`
2. `a[1]++ => a = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]`
3. `a[8]++ => a = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, ...]`
4. `a[7]++ => a = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, ...]`
5. `a[6]++ => a = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, ...]`
6. `a[7]++ => a = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, ...]`

At this point, you have all you need to print them sorted:

```
for(i=0; i <= 1000000; i++)
{
    while(a[i] != 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        a[i]--;
    }
}
```

This second `for` loop iterates over all the elements of `a`, i.e., all the 'counters'. When a counter is larger than 0, you print `i` a number of times equal to the value of the counter. Recall that `i` is not only the position of the current element of the array in this loop, but it is also the number associated to the counter.

This is a clever algorithm that requires no comparisons, but it has some pitfalls.

1. You can sort only integers, e.g. no floats.
2. You can sort only positive integers, e.g. no negative integers.
3. The maximum value of the integers to sort is limited by the length of the array.
4. If you have to sort just 2 numbers, and these numbers are 1 and 1000, you will need an array of length 1001.

The implementation of the algorithm can be modified to solve or mitigate the above issues.

If you want to read more about this topic, see [Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the array should be a[1000001], or the for loop should be `for(i=0;i<1000000;i++)`. Assuming second one for the answer

As I can understand, the maximum number allowed in the array must be 999999.
The main logic of the program(implementing Count Sort) is:

1. Calculate the Frequency of each possible number in range(0 - 999999).
2. Iterate through each possible number from 0 to 999999 and check its frequency, printing it the number of times it appeared in the original array

---

`int a[1000000];`: This declares an array to hold the frequencies of each number from 0 - 999999, with frequency of each number at same index as the number itself, i.e. Frequency of a number n will be at a[n].

---

```
for(i=0;i<t;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&temp);
    a[temp]++;
}
```

This code scans each element and updates its frequency(increasing by 1 for each occurrence).

---

```
for(i=0;i<=1000000;i++)
{
    while(a[i]!=0)
    {
        printf("%d\n",i);
        a[i]--;
    }
}
```

This traverses through each element from 0 - 999999, and for each element:
    Prints the element and decreases its frequency by 1 until its frequency becomes 0, i.e., Prints the element same number of times as its frequency.

---

**Why this Works?**

We are given an array to be sorted in ascending order(assumed from code).
Ascending order means smaller number first.

So, we started from smallest number possible from range, and check if its present or not. If its present in array, we print it the number of times it occurs in the array. Once smallest number is done, we proceed to next smallest number and repeat the same.

Repeating the same till 999999 will make sure the printed array is now in ascending order, as we printed the array with smaller number first, and same times as original array, So, no number will appear more or less than in original array.